# Ipa file not downloaded in IOS7

Tags: xcode

I have created a .ipa file which is not downloaded in Iphone5s with Ios7.Is it problem with Xcode that does not support for Ios7?My Mac osx  10.6.8 and Xcode 4.2

Comment: no.it does not downloaded from Adhoc

Comment: what do you mean by does not downloaded ? Do u mean to say XCode does not makes IPA file or you mean your device is unable to download the IPA ?

Comment: yes Iphone5s not download Ipa file